# Is there a way to change the TeXworks' generated pdf background and text color?

Tags: fonts, pdftex, color, pagecolor

I had just changed the main LaTex in Texworks writing block (or .tex) to "dark mode", however I am struggling with changing the generated pdf file to one. There must be font color controlling and background color controlling files that are editable, right?

Comment: E.g.,`\usepackage{xcolor}\pagecolor{black}\color{white}` -- but do you really want the pdf itself to have a dark background and light text? Good luck printing that! Some PDF viewers will invert colors for you (zathura, sioyek, etc.) so the document still has black text on white background but it displays the reverse in screen so it's less strain on the eyes.